# Activiti and ApacheDS integration purpose

Tags: activiti, apacheds, identity-management

I'm new in Activiti, and I can't grasp the reason for what to use Activiti + ApacheDS

> NOTE In Activiti, there’s no validation if the user who claims the
>   user task is also part of the candidate user or group. The Engine
>   doesn’t even validate whether the user is known. This makes it easy to
>   plug in your own identity management solution, which can, for example,
>   be an LDAP repository. It’s a best practice to
>   define a list of candidate users or groups and only claim the user
>   task with a user that’s on this list. The validation logic that checks
>   if a user exists in your identity management system and whether the
>   user is part of a specific group must be implemented by you.

But I can specify the users & groups for each task by the Activiti possibilities without ApacheDS. Moreover, after authentification, user information stores in the application, so I don't need to ask ApacheDS every time.

**My question is:**

*For what should I use Activity and ApacheDS integration?*

Answer (score 1):

Often users and groups are defined in a LDAP directory. But you can use it without LDAP.

Some reasons to integrate a LDAP could be:

- LDAP Password checking
- Autoprovisioning: When the user does not already exist in Activiti, auto create the user entries.
- Read the group information from LDAP, instead of Activiti
- Read user permissions from LDAP (e.g. who can start a process).

If you user Activiti-Explorer, you could also do a Single Sign-On integration so that user groups and permissions are provided by the sign-on respone (e.g. SAML2 Assertion). (This could also be used for on-the-fly user provisioning.)